# what technologies to use for Collaborative Web App Networking

Tags: javascript, html, networking, canvas

I'm wanting to create a web app where people can collaborate with a specified image.

For example, if you take a look at this basketball app
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.canica.apps.basket&hl=en

I'm envisioning something similar where people can log in, draw plays etc,
I want updates to happen in real time, so that other people logged in as a team see what others are 'drawing'.

I was thinking of extending a html canvas drawing app and adding network communication, but I'm not sure where to start looking.

My question is - What technologies should I be looking at for pushing the data out to the users? 
Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Interesting that this was closed and I tend to disagree. The question is actually quite a good one but should have been restructured. Key points are collaboration, web, HTML5, realtime communication, canvas for drawing and web browsers. There is then clearly a number of factual answers to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've almost answered your own question, especially with your use of HTML5 and JavaScript tag.

You should take a look at WebSockets ([what](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), [what and why](http://pusher.com/websockets)).

WebSockets allow for bi-directional communication between any client and server. Originally only available in web browsers via JavaScript but there are now a number of [WebSocket client libraries](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide#websocket-client-libraries) available which mean that whilst you can develop with browsers in mind there's no reason why you client can't be any device.

A quick search came up with [this example](http://draw.2x.io/). There is also this [iPad/iPhone application](http://jzlabs.com/stuff/marblepaint/).

There also appears to be a video tutorial that uses node.js and socket.io here:
http://wesbos.com/html5-canvas-websockets-nodejs/

If you don't want to worry about installing and maintaining your own realtime infrastructure that also deals with fallback techniques for older web browsers then you might consider using a [hosted realtime web service](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide#hosted-services).

Answer (score 0):

XMPP might be something to look into.  A great book about interacting with XMPP servers from the browser is [Professional XMPP Programming With JavaScript and jQuery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470540710).

It's a pretty soft introduction and I think there might even be a chapter in there that covers  implementing something similar.